# how can i use two event in onPress with react-native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

i want to use UploadB function and setModalVisible(!modalVisible)...

i've try this but it doesn't work

```
    const UploadB = useCallback(() => {
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_POST_REQUEST,
        info:{foodname, ingre1, ingre2, ingre3, recipe},
      }),
      navigation.navigate('Main');
    }, [foodname, ingre1, ingre2, ingre3, recipe]);


         <Pressable
          style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
          onPress={ UploadB, () => setModalVisible(!modalVisible) }
        >
```

how can i fix my code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assing only one function to `onPress`. You can always create a function that does everything you need, both calling UploadB and toggling the modals visibility.

```
const press = useCallback(() => {
  UploadB()
  setModalVisible(visible => !visible)
}, [UploadB]);

<Pressable
  style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
  onPress={press}
/>
```

To remove modalVisibile as a dependency of press, or any state setter to depend on the state itself, you can pass function to the state setter (`setModalVisible`) that will take the current value as its first argument and return new value.